# dompdf slow processing in laravel

Tags: laravel, dompdf

When I used laravel-dompdf, for a small number of users, it runs okay. But when I generated dummy data and try to download the pdf, it takes too much time for it too querying and process the whole thing.
Here is a sample of data that I want to output, I thought maybe the empty conditional statement might affect it, but removing it also wont solve anything.

**Blade**

```
<tbody>
        @foreach ($profile as $data)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->users->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->contact_no }}</td>
            <td>{{ Illuminate\Support\Carbon::parse($data->date_of_birth)->format('d M Y') }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->address }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->batch_year }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->graduation_year }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->job_title }}</td>
            <td>{{ empty($data->facebook) ? '-' : $data->facebook }}</td>
            <td>{{ empty($data->twitter) ? '-' : $data->twitter }}</td>
            <td>{{ empty($data->linkedin) ? '-' : $data->linkedin }}</td>
            <td>{{ empty($data->instagram) ? '-' : $data->instagram }}</td>
            <td>{{ $data->course }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
```

**Controller**

```
$data = Profile::all();
        view()->share('profile', $data);
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', $data)
        ->setPaper('A2', 'landscape')
        ->setWarnings(false)
        ->save('ALUMNI-LIST-AS-OF-'. Carbon::now()
        ->format('d-M-Y') .'.pdf');

        return $pdf->stream('ALUMNI-LIST-AS-OF-'. Carbon::now()->format('d-M-Y') .'.pdf');
```

Comment: You said that it takes too much time for it. Can you provide the actual time approximately? is that something like 20-30 seconds, 1 minute, or something like that ?? Also what's your OS ?

Comment: I'm asking that, cuz for similar situations it depends on php extensions.

Comment: @boolfalse, more than 60 seconds, then it triggered a maximum execution time. I guess if I extend the max exec time, it would take much longer.

Comment: do you use linux? if so, then make sure that you have necessary extensions. For that you can run this: "sudo apt install php7.4-gd" (replace 7.4 with your version if need), as the DOMPDF is part of PHP-GD library. Or (I recommend) you can install some useful extensions as well: "sudo apt install php7.4-gd php7.4-common php7.4-bcmath php7.4-zip php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring php7.4-curl php7.4-cli php7.4-mcrypt php7.4-opcache" (replace 7.4 with your version if need)

Comment: After that restart your server and try to run your request again.

Comment: Currently I'm in local development on Windows. What's the equivalent to sudo for me install all the extensions? Or it's not possible? @boolfalse

Comment: for windows I don't remember, but find your "php.ini" file (the location depends on which webserver or program you use, you can google it and find). Just make sure that it's uncommented. I mean the line ";extension=php_gd2.dll", or it can be ";extension=gd" or something like that (extension containing "gd"). Just remove prefix ";" for uncommenting, and save that file. After that restart your server. I'm not sure this can help, but at least you must have that extension enabled.

Comment: For example the location might be something like this for XAMPP: "C:\xampp\php\php.ini"

Comment: it is a guess but if you are saying that to much data is causing it, then sometimes problem in page alignment leads to the process of conversion to pdf get hanged maybe something like that happened try to page break the tables, also if you are using bootstrap or any other css with size of more than 100kb it will break it

Comment: Also see https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#limitations-known-issues

Answer (score 0):

just faced this problem today xD.

that's happen because loading external CSS makes load time huge.

But inline CSS solves it, so i just pasted entire bootstrap into style tags and that will make the load time normal.